# What is the most efficient way of splitting a string and ensuring there are no duplicates in the resulting array?

Tags: javascript, regex, arrays

I am splitting a javscript string into an array whose elements just contain sequences of cyrillic characters.

```
    var text = "где по его проекту был реализован первый в мире компьютер с хранимой в памяти программой — ACE."
    text=text.toLowerCase();
    var re = /[^йцукенгшщзхъёэждлорпавыфячсмитьбю]+/;
    words = text.split(re);
```

In the above snippet words will contain the following

```
["где", "по", "его", "проекту", "был", "реализован", "первый", "в", "мире", "компьютер", "с", "хранимой", "в", "памяти", "программой", ""]
```

I need to remove the duplicate from the array. Namely I should only see the occurence of "в" once. I know I can after the split and go through the array doing this but not sure what is the best way. Is it possible to do this with the split regex?

Jonathan

Comment: Please define "efficient".

Comment: I guess by efficient I mean the most elegant of idiomatic javascript way to do this.

Comment: Efficient performance and elegant syntax are very often polar opposites.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to go through the array. You can remember whether you've seen instances of the string before using an object as a map, e.g.:

```
var a = /* ...get the array... */;
var unique = [];
var n, len;
var str;
var seen = {};
for (n = 0, len = a.length; n < len; ++n) {
    str = a[n];
    if (!seen[str]) {
        seen[str] = true;
        unique.push(str);
    }
}
```

If there's any chance one of the string values may be a name that already exists on objects (so, `"toString"`, `"valueOf"`, `"hasOwnProperty"`, and such), you have to modify the `if (!seen[str])` check to use `hasOwnProperty` instead:

```
if (!seen.hasOwnProperty(str)) {
```

...but if the strings are as you've shown, you don't need that. Another alternative is to use a prefix like "xx":

```
var keystr = "xx" + str;
if (!seen[keystr]) {
    seen[keystr] = true;
    // ...
}
```

Since there are no object properties on raw objects that start with `"xx"`, and almost certainly never will be.

---

In a comment you've said:

> I guess by efficient I mean the most elegant of idiomatic javascript way to do this.

Interesting, that's not a definition I'd've used. :-) Okay, here's another approach using ES5's `filter`, which is definitely more JavaScript-y:

```
var a = /* ...get the array... */;
var seen = {};
a = a.filter(function(str) {
    if (!seen[str]) {
        seen[str] = true;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
});
```

Comment: (I start with hasOwnProperty for existence-of checks.)

Comment: @user2864740: I don't when there's no chance of collisions, as in this case. Or I use a prefix for the flags. But I always mention it, so people are aware of the issue.

Comment: Why leave in the/any chance to begin with? Desiring chaining is usually less common for me to run into ..

Comment: @user2864740: Again, in this case (or with a prefix), there *is* no chance. But my reasons are primarily that `hasOwnProperty` is clunky. (It's also slow, but it's *extremely* unlikely that that's going to matter...)

Comment: I like `Object.keys()` for this purpose :) It also deals with the `.hasOwnProperty()` issue. Also, `.reduce()`.

Comment: I like the first comment as it seems shorter but I will go with this answer because it performs better.

Answer (score 7):

Not the most efficient, but it's clean and simple.

```
text.split(re).filter(function(str, idx, txtArray) {
    return txtArray.indexOf(str) === idx; 
});
```

Basically, if the first index found doesn't match the current index in the iteration, it's a duplicate.

Comment: It's clever .. takes a second to grok though.

Comment: +1 And an excellent proof of your comment on the question: *"Efficient performance and elegant syntax are very often polar opposites."* :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: Thanks. Yours is definitely the way to go if performance is at all a concern.

Comment: Maybe, but this is just so much prettier... :-)

Comment: @VaccinalBowl: Honestly, in practice I'd use T.J. Crowder's answer. Just put the code in a function, have it receive the original, and return the new, and you're set.

Comment: Can you please tell me why this answer is not as suitable as T.J Crowders answer. I am quite new to javascript and don't understand the details. I have tried your code above and it works perfectly for me.

Comment: I guess that this method is two nested for loops?

Comment: @VaccinalBowl: Right. For every element in the Array, we're searching the array until we find the first element. That's quite a lot of searching, especially on long arrays. Both will work, but in practice I'd use T.J.'s answer, but put it in a function used like `myarr = makeUnique(myarr);`

Answer (score 2):

If you are willing to use a third party library, then I would recommend to have a look at [Underscore](http://underscorejs.org/). This Library provides a `uniq` method, that you would apply in the following way:

```
words = _.uniq(text.split(re));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the "prettiness" of the `.indexOf` solution using some other built-in functions:

```
var uniq = Object.keys(text.split(re).reduce(function(words, word) {
  words[word] = null;
  return words;
}, {}));
```

This'll only work in newer versions of JavaScript (that is, not old versions of IE). This has the advantage, like Mr. Crowder's version, of not being an *O(n<sup>2</sup>)* algorithm. On fairly large strings without many duplicates (say, a page full of text), those `.indexOf()` calls will start to warm up the client CPU.

Note that this will give you the unique words in no particular order.

Answer (score 0):

How about using negative lookahead in the regex and use the .match method to return the array of matches.

```
([йцукенгшщзхъёэждлорпавыфячсмитьбю]+)(?!.*\1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this (splitter : `" "`) :

```
var m = 'azerty rty aze rty aze'
    .replace(/(^| )([^ ]+)(?= |$)(?=.* \2( |$))/g, '') // removes duplicates
    .match(/[^ ]+/g) 
m; // ["azerty", "rty", "aze"]
```

Surely not the most efficient way though.